# Elastic search : How to search in two documents in single index?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I've two documents configured in a single index named inventory.

1. profile (this have users and mobile information)
2. p2p-relation

Inventory index mapping properties are as follows :

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "type": {"type": "keyword"},
            "id": {"type": "keyword"},
            "sourceId": {"type": "keyword"},
            "targetId": {"type": "keyword"},
            "firstName": {"type": "text"},
            "lastName": {"type": "text"},
            "createdBy": {"type": "text"},
            "p_type": {"type": "text"},
            "model": {"type": "text"},
            "OS": {"type": "keyword"}
            }
        }
}
```

profile has the following information

**users :**

```
{   "type":"profile",   "id" : "user1", "p_type" : "user",  "firstName" : "Ashok", "lastName" : "S" }
{   "type":"profile",   "id" : "user2", "p_type" : "user",  "firstName" : "Arun", "lastName" : "V" }
```

**mobiles :**

```
{   "type":"profile",   "id" : "mobile1", "p_type" : "mobile",  "model" : "samsung", "OS" : "Android" }
{   "type":"profile",   "id" : "mobile2", "p_type" : "mobile",  "model" : "iPhone", "OS" : "iOS" }
```

**p2p-relation** has the which user used which mobile information :

```
{   "type":"p2p-relation",  "id" : "user1-owns-mobile1", "sourceId" : "user1",  "targetId" : "mobile1", "createdBy" : "admin" }
{   "type":"p2p-relation",  "id" : "user1-owns-mobile2", "sourceId" : "user1",  "targetId" : "mobile2", "createdBy" : "admin" }
```

In our business case, we need to retrieve the list of android/iOS mobiles owned by an user which we get as input from the customer.

That is, if the user1 requests for **/mymobiles?query=os==Android** , it should translate this into ES and expecting

**{ "type":"profile",   "id" : "mobile1", "p_type" : "mobile",  "model" : "samsung", "OS" : "Android" }**

as the result and if the user2 requests for the same, it should return empty.

I've tried with query and bool. But it search only within a single document. How to achieve this  in elastic search ?

Comment: can you share your index mapping and these `types` , profile and `p2p-relation` are part of same index or they are different types of ES index, which version of elastic you are using?

Comment: Both 'profile' and 'p2p-relation' are stored within the same index. And using 7.4.0 version.

Comment: Updated the question with index mapping.

Comment: I don't see `p_type` in your mapping

Comment: Sorry. I'll update that in mappings. p_type, model, and OS also present in the mapping.

Comment: Please update the proper mapping and provide all the information required to provide the solution

Comment: Updated with the proper mapping. And this is a simple data. In real time usage, user can have n-number of mobile phones assigned to that user by the system admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above model falls under many to many relationship data model. An user can have many mobile phones assigned to him and a mobile device can be assigned to many users over the period of time. 
So changed the data model to storing it as nested objects.

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
        "type": {"type": "keyword"},
        "id": {"type": "keyword"},
        "firstName": {"type": "text"},
        "lastName": {"type": "text"},
        "createdBy": {"type": "text"},
        "model": {"type": "text"},
        "OS": {"type": "keyword"},
        "mobiles" : {
            "type" : "nested",
            "properties" : {
                "id": {"type": "keyword"},
                "model": {"type": "text"},
                "OS": {"type": "keyword"},
                "createdBy": {"type": "text"}
            }
        },
        "users" : {
            "type" : "nested",
            "properties" : {
                "id": {"type": "keyword"},
                "firstName": {"type": "keyword"},
                "lastName": {"type": "keyword"},
                "createdBy": {"type": "text"}                               
            }
        }
}}}
```

But the pain is, whenever a mobile phone is assigned to an user, I have the extra effort of updating two rows.

Data stored as follows

```
{   "type":"profile",   "id" : "user1",  "firstName" : "Ashok", "lastName" : "S", "mobiles" : [ {"id" : "uuid1", "model": "samsung", "OS" : "Android"}] }

{   "type":"profile",   {"id" : "uuid1", "model": "samsung", "OS" : "Android"}, "users" : [ "id" : "user1",  "firstName" : "Ashok", "lastName" : "S"] }
```

And to answer the  /mymobiles?query=os==Android, I've used the following query .

```
{ 
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [ 
            {
              { "term": {"OS": "android"} },
              "nested": {
                "path": "users",
                "query": {
                  "bool": {
                    "must": [ {"term": {"users.id": "user1"} }]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
        ]   
    }
}}
```

I've referred the following link to do this : https://medium.com/@mena.meseha/briefly-describe-how-to-store-complex-relational-data-in-elasticsearch-f30277317b1